# Filter / subset rows that contain anything other than certain strings

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have data frame with columns containing strings and want to **filter out all rows that contain anything other than certain strings**.

Consider a simplified example below:

```
string <- c('AA', 'BB' , 'AA, BB' , 'BB, AA', 'AAS', 'BB, CC',  'DD', 'A','A, BB', 'BBAA', 'AA,BB')
df <- data.frame(string)
```

And I would like to maintain only those strings that does not contain anything else than `'AA'` and/or `'BB'`:

```
AA
BB
AA, BB
BB, AA
BBAA
AA,BB
```

Please note that this is a **simplified example and you cannot simply filter for AAS, CC and DD or the combinations of AA and BB**, as there many more alternative string options.

Comment: so then what are you trying to drop? Why are you dropping `AAS` or `CC`?

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(string, "C|D|S", negate=T))
  string
```

or

```
pattern=c('C', 'D', 'S')
df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(
        stringr::str_detect(string, paste(pattern, collapse="|"), negate=T)
)
```

```
1     AA
2     BB
3 AA, BB
4 BB, AA
```

Comment: As mentioned: "_Please note that this is a simplified example and you cannot simply filter for AAS, CC and DD or the combinations of AA and BB, as there many more alternative string options._" The string_detect "C|D|S" or the pattern=c('C', 'D', 'S') would be come endless ans thus the solution is not option for me.

Comment: @MsGISRocker I'm not clear on what you are actually asking for then.

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   filter(lengths(str_extract_all(string, "\\b(AA|BB)\\b")) == 
        str_count(string, "\\w+"))
```

-output

```
 string
1     AA
2     BB
3 AA, BB
4 BB, AA
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$string, ",\\s*"), function(x) 
    all(x %in% c("AA", "BB"))),, drop = FALSE]
  string
1     AA
2     BB
3 AA, BB
4 BB, AA
```

---

With the new data, we could do

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$string, "(?<=AA)[, ]*(?=BB)|(?<=BB)[, ]*(?=AA)",
     perl = TRUE), function(x) any(c("AA", "BB") %in% x)),, drop = FALSE]
   string
1      AA
2      BB
3  AA, BB
4  BB, AA
10   BBAA
11  AA,BB
```

---

or using `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate(string, into = c("a", "b"), 
   sep = "(?<=AA)[, ]*(?=BB)|(?<=BB)[, ]*(?=AA)", remove = FALSE) %>% 
   filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . %in% c("AA", "BB"))) %>% 
   select(string)
string
1     AA
2     BB
3 AA, BB
4 BB, AA
5   BBAA
6  AA,BB
```

Comment: @arkun: The solution works for the example supplied before, but does not completely answer the question"***filter out all rows that contain anything other than certain strings.***" I added more examples of strings to be matched or not to be matched by the filter.

Answer (score 0):

**A solution with stringr - remove the filtering patterns then count the remaining chars**

The OP updated the data, and suggested the filtered strings should have nothing but the desired patterns "AA" and "BB". The desired operation is not very clear, but this will get us the desired output:

First, remove the inclusion patterns ("AA|BB"), then `str_count` the remaining word characters (`\\w`) and filter only the rows in which the count is zero:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% filter(str_remove_all(string, "AA|BB") %>%
                      str_count("\\w")==0)
```

**output**

```
  string
1     AA
2     BB
3 AA, BB
4 BB, AA
5   BBAA
6  AA,BB
```

**data**

```
string <- c('AA', 'BB' , 'AA, BB' , 'BB, AA', 'AAS', 'BB, CC',  'DD', 'A','A, BB', 'BBAA', 'AA,BB')
df <- data.frame(string)
```

Comment: The comment for arkun applies also to your solution. Thanks, best MGR

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Please tell me if you need any changes.